# Android get multiple inputs from single EditText

Tags: android, oop

```
    userInputs.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
                    int val = (Integer) userInputs.getTag();
                    switch (val) {
                    case USER_INP_NAME:
                        newUser = new Users();
                        newUser.setUsersName(userInputs.getText()
                                .toString());
                        userInputs.setTag(USER_INP_NUMBER);
                        userInputs.setText("");
                        userInputs.setHint("User Name");
                        break;
                    case USER_INP_NUMBER:
                        newUser.setUnitWeight(Integer
                                .parseInt(userInputs.getText().toString()));
                        userInputs.setTag(USER_INP_STATE);
                        userInputs.setText("");
                        userInputs.setHint("User Number");
                        break;
                    case USER_INP_STATE:
                        newUser.setShelfLife(Integer
                                .parseInt(userInputs.getText().toString()));
                        userInputs.setTag(USER_INP_NAME);
                        userInputs.setText("");
                        userInputs.setHint("User State");
                        uList.add(newUser);
                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                    }

                default:
                    break;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Scenario - 
It's an android app and there is a EditText box, and I need to accept multiple types of inputs one after another in order. This order is predefined. On `USER_INP_NAME` object `newUser` is created. After this muliple properties are set with this object. Finally on `USER_INP_STATE` the object is added to a list. This cycle repeates.

I am a "C" programmer, so coded in procedure oriented manner. The switch case is looking ugly for now, is there a better solution to do this ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you want to use the same EditText for all 3 inputs?

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex. For example:

```
public String currentInput(String input){
    if(input.matches("[0-9]*")){
        return "numbers only";
    }
    if(input.matches("Some RegEx")){
        return "something else..";
    }
    if(...
}
```